# Segmentation fault in a two dimensional array using scanf

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, scanf

I've been getting segmentation fault in this piece of code, in the part where I `scanf` for the values of the board. In the beginning, I scan two times for the dimensions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "maxsum.h"
int main() {
    int x,y,n,m,**board;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    board=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if (board==NULL)  {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory \n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)  {
        *(board+x)=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
        if (*(board+x)==NULL)  {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory \n");
            return 1;
        } 
    } 
    for (x=0;x<n;x++)  {
        for (y=0;y<m;y++)  {
            scanf("%d",&board[x][y]); // the error happens in this line ,and only when variable x is about to become n-1 when n>4 (very confused as to why)// 
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n",Solve(n,m,board)); //not relevant //
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `board=malloc(n*sizeof(int));` -> `board=malloc(n*sizeof(*board));`

Comment: Or at least `board=malloc(n*sizeof(int*));`

Answer (score 0):

You're not allocating the right amount of memory:

```
board=malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

You're setting up `board` as an array of `int *`, but you're only allocating space for an array of `int`.  Most likely an `int` is smaller than an `int *` on your system, so you're not allocating enough.  You subsequently write past the end of allocated memory resulting in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change this allocation to:

```
board=malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
```

Or better yet:

```
board=malloc(n*sizeof(*board));
```